# Callout for annotation view is cut-off in macOS(Mac-catalyst) app

Tags: ios, macos, mkannotationview, mac-catalyst

I am having an issue with annotation view which is shown on Map view.

The call out view on clicking on pin does not showing full address text.

Reference Image

[image: mapwithpin]

This is working in iOS but not working in Mac catalyst app.

Please help if anyone have any idea.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `MKPinAnnotationView` which is deprecated.

Please switch to `MKMarkerAnnotationView`.
The new class has many advantages.